# Uploading Video to third party services should be performed at where?

Tags: video, frontend, backend, uploading

Currently, I am doing an application that allowed users to upload their own videos to third party services like Vimeo, Cloudinary.

It can be performed either in front-end or back-end. 
**What is the best practice way to perform this action? 
And what is the cons and pros between them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Videos are generally large files or streams, even short ones, relative to other data and media types.

Unless there is a reason you need them on your own backend, to do some pre-processing or to modify or add to them for example, it would generally be easier to use the SDK's that Vimeo etc provide to upload directly to the video hosting site from your app on your users mobiles.